# How to find real roots of an equation

Tags: calculus

How to find the real roots of this equation

$e^x-x^2=0$

I am aware that this can be solved by Rolle's theorem. This is an increasing function hence derivative. But how to test for continuity. We haven't given any points? And what about $f(a)=f(b)$, as required for Rolle's theorem?

One more thing that l m looking about...As many times the graph cuts the $x$ axis is equal to the total no. Of roots of that equation. Does strictly monotonically increasing function cuts the $x$ axis only once??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $e^x−x^2$ is the difference of two continuous functions, it is continuous. 
Notice $e^{-2}-(-2)^2 <0$ and $e^{1}-(1)^2 >0$. So by the Intermediate value theorem there exist $x\in(-2,1)$ such that $e^x−x^2=0$.

Since it is strictly increasing I don't think you can apply Rolle's theorem. 
As per your last edit, yes if a function is strictly monotonically increasing then it can only cross the $x$-axis at most one time.

Comment: How did u select the two points?? Arbitrarily?? Seems the coefficient.

Comment: Not arbitrarily. Note $e^x<1$ for $x<0$ so for the left endpoint I picked a number smaller than $0$ that would guarantee the function is negative and same way I picked  the right endpoint.